# Variable not defined error for loading external GeoJSON into Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis, geojson

I've seen a variety of answers addressing this question using AJAX, but I'd like to keep this very simple, as I think it is and I don't have any idea why mine isn't working.

I have all the leaflet files in my html, I've done both CDN and downloaded, and they're in the right order. I have an external geoJSON file. I have saved it as sitesAtRisk.js and linked to it in a script tag in my index file.

sitesAtRisk.js looks like:

```
var sitesAtRisk = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Ida_9-10_AllSitesatRisk",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": null, "Site_Name": "Nutmeg Valley Road", "Site_Score": 42.69, "Site_EPA_ID": "CTD980669261", "SEMS_ID": 100250, "SITS_ID": 8, "Region_ID": 1, "State": "Connecticut", "City": "Wolcott", "County": "New Haven", "Status": "Deleted NPL Site", "Longitude": -72.9986, "Latitude": 41.5748, "Proposed_Date": "01\/22\/1987", "Listing_Date": "03\/31\/1989", "Construction_Completion_Date": "09\/28\/2004", "Construction_Completion_Number": 922, "NOID_Date": "08\/05\/2005", "Deletion_Date": "09\/23\/2005", "Site_Listing_Narrative": "<a href=\"https:\/\/semspub.epa.gov\/src\/document\/01\/75001286\" target=\"_blank\">CTD980669261 (PDF)<\/a>", "Site_Progress_Profile": "<a href=\"https:\/\/cumulis.epa.gov\/supercpad\/cursites\/csitinfo.cfm?id=0100250\" target=\"_blank\">Nutmeg Valley Road<\/a>", "Notice_of_Data_Availability": null, "Proposed_FR_Notice": "<a href=\"https:\/\/semspub.epa.gov\/src\/document\/11\/189645\" target=\"_blank\">01\/22\/1987 (PDF)<\/a>", "Deletion_FR_Notice": "<a href=\"http:\/\/www.gpo.gov\/fdsys\/pkg\/FR-2005-09-23\/pdf\/05-19054.pdf\" target=\"_blank\">09\/23\/2005 (PDF)<\/a>", "Final_FR_Notice": "<a href=\"https:\/\/semspub.epa.gov\/src\/document\/11\/189631\" target=\"_blank\">03\/31\/1989 (PDF)<\/a>", "NOID_FR_Notice": "<a href=\"http:\/\/www.gpo.gov\/fdsys\/pkg\/FR-2005-08-05\/pdf\/05-15435.pdf\" target=\"_blank\">08\/05\/2005 (PDF)<\/a>", "Restoration_FR_Notice_Jumper_Pa": null, "Site_has_had_a_Partial_Deletion": "No", "CreationDate": null, "Creator": null, "EditDate": null, "Editor": null, "ObjectId2": 1, "WFO": "OKX", "ISSUED": "202109020208", "EXPIRED": "202109020430", "INIT_ISS": "202109020208", "INIT_EXP": "202109020430", "PHENOM": "FF", "GTYPE": "P", "SIG": "W", "ETN": "41", "STATUS_2": "NEW", "NWS_UGC": null, "AREA_KM2": 4599.3081514083324, "UPDATED": "202109020208", "HV_NWSLI": "00000", "HV_SEV": "0", "HV_CAUSE": "ER", "HV_REC": "OO", "EMERGENC": 1, "POLY_BEG": "202109020208", "POLY_END": "202109020403", "WINDTAG": null, "HAILTAG": null, "TORNTAG": null, "DAMAGTAG": null, "POINTID": null, "TCSRG30": null, "OBJECTID_2": null, "RADII": null, "STORMID": null, "BASIN": null, "STORMNUM": null, "STARTDTG": null, "ENDDTG": null, "STORMNAME": null, "Shape__Area": null, "Shape__Length": null, "layer": "NPL Sites in WW", "path": "\/Users\/michaelgordner\/Desktop\/2021 Hurricanes\/Ida 2021\/Ida_WWNPLSites_northeastonly.geojson|layername=Ida_WWNPLSites_northeastonly" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ -8126166.980621860362589, 5097497.82189555093646 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "OBJECTID": null, "Site_Name": "Durham Meadows", "Site_Score": 33.94, "Site_EPA_ID": "CTD001452093", "SEMS_ID": 100108, "SITS_ID": 9, "Region_ID": 1, "State": "Connecticut", "City": "Durham", "County": "Middlesex", "Status": "NPL Site", "Longitude": -72.681388, "Latitude": 41.48111, "Proposed_Date": "06\/24\/1988", "Listing_Date": "10\/04\/1989", "Construction_Completion_Date": null, "Construction_Completion_Number": 0, "NOID_Date": null, "Deletion_Date": null, "Site_Listing_Narrative": "<a href=\"https:\/\/semspub.epa.gov\/src\/document\/01\/75001287\" target=\"_blank\">CTD001452093 (PDF)<\/a>", "Site_Progress_Profile": "<a href=\"https:\/\/cumulis.epa.gov\/supercpad\/cursites\/csitinfo.cfm?id=0100108\" target=\"_blank\">Durham Meadows<\/a>", "Notice_of_Data_Availability": null, "Proposed_FR_Notice": "<a href=\"https:\/\/semspub.epa.gov\/src\/document\/11\/189648\" target=\"_blank\">06\/24\/1988 (PDF)<\/a>", "Deletion_FR_Notice": null, "Final_FR_Notice": "<a href=\"https:\/\/semspub.epa.gov\/src\/document\/11\/189633\" target=\"_blank\">10\/04\/1989 (PDF)<\/a>", "NOID_FR_Notice": null, "Restoration_FR_Notice_Jumper_Pa": null, "Site_has_had_a_Partial_Deletion": "No", "CreationDate": null, "Creator": null, "EditDate": null, "Editor": null, "ObjectId2": 2, "WFO": "OKX", "ISSUED": "202109020406", "EXPIRED": "202109020923", "INIT_ISS": "202109020406", "INIT_EXP": "202109021000", "PHENOM": "FF", "GTYPE": "P", "SIG": "W", "ETN": "44", "STATUS_2": "NEW", "NWS_UGC": null, "AREA_KM2": 2964.2400633172942, "UPDATED": "202109020406", "HV_NWSLI": "00000", "HV_SEV": "0", "HV_CAUSE": "ER", "HV_REC": "OO", "EMERGENC": 0, "POLY_BEG": "202109020406", "POLY_END": "202109020923", "WINDTAG": null, "HAILTAG": null, "TORNTAG": null, "DAMAGTAG": null, "POINTID": null, "TCSRG30": null, "OBJECTID_2": null, "RADII": null, "STORMID": null, "BASIN": null, "STORMNUM": null, "STARTDTG": null, "ENDDTG": null, "STORMNAME": null, "Shape__Area": null, "Shape__Length": null, "layer": "NPL Sites in WW", "path": "\/Users\/michaelgordner\/Desktop\/2021 Hurricanes\/Ida 2021\/Ida_WWNPLSites_northeastonly.geojson|layername=Ida_WWNPLSites_northeastonly" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ -8090855.102308344095945, 5083566.382400194182992 ] ] } }
...... //to the end of the file
```

script.js:

```
//Initiate Map

var map = L.map('mapid').setView([41.953397, -87.708614], 3.5);


//Add base/tile layer
L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    subdomains: ['a','b','c']
}).addTo( map );

//Add geoJSON

L.geoJson(sitesAtRisk).addTo(map)

//I also tried 
function addSites (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup("<h1>I'm a site</h1>")
}
L.geoJson(sitesAtRisk, {
    onEachFeature: addSites
}).addTo(map)
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: [No error for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/d4A57Q0y8F9b7fPz). Your GeoJSON is not compliant, BTW - all coordinates shall be in EPSG:4326 as per the specs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and below is how i resolved it.

1. Ensure the the Script.js file is called after the sitesAtRisk.js.
2. Ensure you have the right geoJson file from the right source , if not sure follow the link below for sample file and rename it to .js after downloading. Hope it helps
   https://geojson.io/#map=2/20.0/0.0
   Regards